# How can I allow python users with a version lower than python2.7 to run my program that uses `sysconfig`?

Tags: python, module, version, packaging, pypi

I made a python program which uses the `sysconfig` module. How can I allow python users with a python version lower than python2.7 to also run that program? I can not find this library in `PyPI`.

Before I had also used `argparse` and this was also not installed by default in python versions lower than python2.7. But I could just add it in my requirements file because it can be downloaded using `pip`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to write a version of your code that works without sysconfig - your code would look something like this:

```
try:
    import sysconfig
    HAS_SYSCONFIG = True
except ImportError:
    HAS_SYSCONFIG = False

...

if HAS_SYSCONFIG:
    # sysconfig code here
else:
    # compatibility code here
```

You could also try backporting `sysconfig` to an earlier version of python and including it with your script, but that may be more work than it's worth.